# .openPopup() & .setView() is not working with folium markers

Tags: folium

I'm trying to implement a search bar to a folium map that would navigate to an existing marker with the same title as the input. However the functions that would do this are not working.

I've tried changing .setView() to .flyto() but that did not work. However .click() seemed to work in getting the popup to show.

Here is the code

```py
search_script = """

<!-- Search bar -->
<div style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); z-index: 1000;">
    <input type="text" id="search-input" placeholder="Search for a park" style="width: 300px; height: 40px; font-size: 16px; border: 2px solid #000; padding: 5px;">
    <button onclick="search()" style="font-size: 16px; padding: 5px 10px; height: 40px;">Search</button>
</div>

<script>
        function search() {
            var searchText = document.getElementById('search-input').value.toLowerCase();
            var markers = document.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-marker-icon');
            
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var marker = markers[i];
                var title = marker.getAttribute('title').toLowerCase();
                
                if (title.includes(searchText)) {
                    marker.openPopup(); <!-- Does not work -->
            map.setView(marker.getLatLng(), 8); <!-- Also does not work -->
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
"""

map.get_root().html.add_child(folium.Element(search_script))
```

UPDATE:
Ok the problem was that
var markers = document.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-marker-icon');
only takes the DOM elements of each marker into the array. So instead, I took the full marker objects into the array which solved the problem of the functions not working.
Here is the js used to do so:

```
var markers = [];
    map_id.eachLayer(function(layer) {
            if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
                markers.push(layer);
            }
        });

    function search() {
        var searchText = document.getElementById('search-input').value.toLowerCase();
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var marker = markers[i];
                var title = marker.options.title.toLowerCase();

                if (title.includes(searchText)) {
            map_id.flyTo(marker.getLatLng(), 16);
            marker.openPopup();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```